# Is it possible to have a "greater than equal to" django queryset filter on just the day of the month of a dateTime?

Tags: django, django-queryset

What I want to do is:

```
MyModel.filter(start_date__day__gte=25)
```

But that doesn't work.  Is there any way to specify a `gte` or a `range` for a date, but only on the day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this would be most efficient without falling back to raw queries or requesting a `__day__gte` method:

```
from django.db.models import Q

day_filter = Q()
for i in xrange(25,32):
    day_filter = day_filter | Q(start_date__day=i)
objects = MyModel.filter(day_filter)
```

Comment: thanks!  My question was a bit oversimplified, this was actually going into a filter that would determine every monday in my database that was in a week that spilled over into the following month... so there was a different criteria for months with 31 days, 30 days, and February... this was the February case.  I ended up with a very long query statement with a lot of nested Q &'s and |'s but it does the job!